# Woocommerce - Use SKU as unique identifier in the order creation with REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I have a website where I want to transfer woocommerce orders. Everything is working very well now but I have a strungle with product pairing. Products ids on testing are not the same as on live website. What do I need to add products to order and pair them not with their ID but with the SKU which is the same on both websites. My code is bellow.

I'm following this structure over here but I have no clue how to pair line items by the SKU `'line_items'`: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#create-an-order

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_gls', 'transfer_order_woo_api', 9999, 3 );
function transfer_order_woo_api( $order_id, $order ) {
   $live_ck = 'ck_some ID';
   $live_cs = 'cs_SOME ID';
   $live_url = 'https://testsite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?consumer_key=' . $live_ck . '&consumer_secret=' . $live_cs;
   $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
   
    // Line items - HERE IS THE PROBLEM 
    $lineitems = array();
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
     $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
     $quantity = $item->get_quantity();
     $product = $item->get_product();
     
    $lineitem = array('quantity' => $quantity,
                     'product_id' => $product_id //I need to pair theese line items by the SKU because the product ID is not the same on different sites but the SKU is the same.
                
                      );
    $lineitems[] = $lineitem;
    }
   
   $body = array(
      'status' => 'processing',
      'meta_data' => array( 
      array( 
         'key' => 'carrier',
         'value' => ''.get_post_meta($order->id, 'ywot_carrier_id', true).''
      ),
      array( 
         'key' => 'order_number',
         'value' => ''.get_post_meta($order->id, '_alg_wc_custom_order_number', true).''
      ),
      array( 
         'key' => 'orderid',
         'value' => $order->get_id(),
      ),
      array( 
         'key' => 'shipped_date',
         'value' => ''.get_post_meta($order->id, 'shipped_date', true).''
      ),
      array( 
         'key' => 'ywot_tracking_code',
         'value' => ''.get_post_meta($order->id, 'ywot_tracking_code', true).''
      )),
      
      'billing' => array(
         'first_name' => $order->get_billing_first_name(),
         'last_name' => $order->get_billing_last_name(),
         'address1' => $order->get_billing_address_1(),
         'city' => $order->get_billing_city(),
         'postcode' => $order->get_billing_postcode(),
         'country' => $order->get_billing_country(),
         'phone' => $order->get_billing_phone(),
      ),
      'shipping' => array(
         'first_name' => $order->get_shipping_first_name(),
         'last_name' => $order->get_shipping_last_name(),
         'address1' => $order->get_shipping_address_1(),
         'city' => $order->get_shipping_city(),
         'postcode' => $order->get_shipping_postcode(),
         'country' => $order->get_shipping_country(),
      ),
      'line_items' => $lineitems,
     
   );
   
   
   $raw_response = wp_remote_post( $live_url, 
      array(
         'headers' => array( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ),
         'timeout' => 30,                    
         'body' => json_encode( $body ),
      )
   );
```

Thanks in advance for your ideas.

---

UPDATE

```
add_action( "woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_gls", "transfer_order_woo_api", 9999, 3 );
function transfer_order_woo_api( $order_id, $order ) {
   $remote_keys = "consumer_key=ck_xxxx&consumer_secret=cs_xxxx";
   $live_url = "https://web.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?{$remote_keys}";
   $line_items = array();

   foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
      $quantity = $item->get_quantity();
      $product = $item->get_product();
      $product_sku = $product->get_sku();

      // retrieve product ID by SKU, return product properties
      $remote_get = wp_remote_get("https://web.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?sku={$product_sku}&{$remote_keys}");
      $remote_product = json_decode($remote_get['body'])[0];
      
      $line_item = array(
                       "quantity" => $quantity,
                       "product_id" => $remote_product->id
                      );

      $line_items[] = $line_item;
   }

 $body = array(
      'status' => 'processing',
      'meta_data' => array( 
      array( 
         'key' => 'carrier',
         'value' => ''.get_post_meta($order->id, 'ywot_carrier_id', true).''
      ),
      array( 
         'key' => 'order_number',
         'value' => ''.get_post_meta($order->id, '_alg_wc_custom_order_number', true).''
      ),
      array( 
         'key' => 'orderid',
         'value' => $order->get_id(),
      ),
      array( 
         'key' => 'shipped_date',
         'value' => ''.get_post_meta($order->id, 'shipped_date', true).''
      ),
      array( 
         'key' => 'ywot_tracking_code',
         'value' => ''.get_post_meta($order->id, 'ywot_tracking_code', true).''
      )),
      
      'billing' => array(
         'first_name' => $order->get_billing_first_name(),
         'last_name' => $order->get_billing_last_name(),
         'address1' => $order->get_billing_address_1(),
         'city' => $order->get_billing_city(),
         'postcode' => $order->get_billing_postcode(),
         'country' => $order->get_billing_country(),
         'phone' => $order->get_billing_phone(),
      ),
      'shipping' => array(
         'first_name' => $order->get_shipping_first_name(),
         'last_name' => $order->get_shipping_last_name(),
         'address1' => $order->get_shipping_address_1(),
         'city' => $order->get_shipping_city(),
         'postcode' => $order->get_shipping_postcode(),
         'country' => $order->get_shipping_country(),
      ),
      'line_items' => $lineitems,
     
   );
   
   
   $raw_response = wp_remote_post( $live_url, 
      array(
         'headers' => array( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ),
         'timeout' => 30,                    
         'body' => json_encode( $body ),
      )
   );

}
```

Comment: The code is in live website and you want to duplicate for each new order via API to testing website. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, code is located at live and trasfering to another website. Problem is that I need to get items by the sku and match them together not by the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve each product ID from the other site using the API `/wp-json/wc/v3/products?sku=xxxxx` (GET) inside your loop. The example as below.

```
add_action( "woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_gls", "transfer_order_woo_api", 9999, 3 );
function transfer_order_woo_api( $order_id, $order ) {
   $remote_keys = "consumer_key=xxxxxx&consumer_secret=xxxxxx";
   $remote_url = "https://testsite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?{$remote_keys}";
   $line_items = array();

   foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
      $quantity = $item->get_quantity();
      $product = $item->get_product();
      $product_sku = $product->get_sku();

      // retrieve product ID by SKU, return product properties
      $remote_get = wp_remote_get("https://testsite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?sku={$product_sku}&{$remote_keys}");
      $remote_product = json_decode($remote_get['body'])[0];
      
      $line_item = array(
                       "quantity" => $quantity,
                       "product_id" => $remote_product->id
                      );

      $line_items[] = $line_item;
   }

   // rest of your code here...
}
```

Comment: It does not work :/ when I run the order status change it does not create order now on the other site. Any idea whats could be wrong?

Comment: Its probably not matching by the same SKUs because we retrieve IDS from the SKUs but the IDS are not the same on both sites. We need to get SKUs and match them with the same product from live on staging.

Comment: What do I need is to get item SKU in the order from live and add the product from the order by the SKU on staging, not by the ID because IDS are not the same in wordpress.

Comment: @LuboMasura do you already have custom order status with the slug 'gls'? you could try adding `print_r($raw_response);` at the end of the function to see whether the code was  executed or not after changing the order status.

Comment: @LuboMasura You're creating an order at test site, so you need to include the product ID in test site inside your line item. `wp_remote_get()` used to get the product ID of test site using SKU from line item of the order in your live site.

Comment: Now I made it work, everything transfers expect product. Strange. I update my question with current code I use. Maybe I did something wrong there?

Comment: @LuboMasura change `"product_id" => $remote_product->sku` to `"product_id" => $remote_product->id`, bear in mind that you need to provide value for `product_id` key, not `product_sku` key which is not possible in that API.

Comment: SKU on live is the same as on staging so I have no clue whats wrong there

Comment: Updated but still not getting the product into order

Comment: Now I updated my question with the current code I use

Comment: @LuboMasura you forgot to change `'line_items' => $lineitems,` to `'line_items' => $line_items,`

Comment: One question for this, is it able to also exclude this code if on staging already order exists?

Comment: @LuboMasura you could try adding custom meta for the order in live site once it has finished copying (after `wp_remote_post`), then you could add a check whether to execute the code if the meta doesn't exist yet at the very beginning of the function.

Comment: Could you also help me with one more question? I will post it now.

Comment: @LuboMasura Sure

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73092219/update-product-with-woocommerce-rest-api-by-the-sku-identifier thank you