# Update product with Woocommerce REST API by the SKU identifier

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce

I need to update the product with the REST API from the live website to staging. It works well if I add a static product ID. What I need is to match products across sites with the SKU, not by the ID because it's not the same.

Any ideas on how to do it? My code is below.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'on_product_savex', 10, 1 );
function on_product_savex( $product_id ) {
   $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
   $get_main_website_product_id = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_sku', true );
   $live_ck = 'ck_xxxx';
   $live_cs = 'cs_xxxx';
   $live_url = 'https://web.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?sku='.$get_main_website_product_id.'&consumer_key=' . $live_ck . '&consumer_secret=' . $live_cs;
   
   
   $body = array(
        'name' => $product->get_name(), // product title
        'status' => 'private', // product status, default: publish
        'regular_price' => $product->get_regular_price(),
        'sale_price' => $product->get_sale_price(),
        'description' => $product->get_description(),
        'sku' => $product->get_sku(),
        'weight' => $product->get_weight(),
        'manage_stock' => true,
        'stock_quantity' => 10,
        
     
   );
   
   print_r( $body );
   $raw_response = wp_remote_post( $live_url, 
      array(
         'headers' => array( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ),
         'timeout' => 30,                    
         'body' => json_encode( $body ),
      )
   );
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to directly update using SKU without custom API endpoint since WooCommerce REST API only support product ID to update the product. Ref: [https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-update-modify-products-from-api-with-sku-as-the-identifier/](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-update-modify-products-from-api-with-sku-as-the-identifier/)

Comment: Ok and we could not do it the same way as with order? Like we will get the product ID with the SKU? I need the same to do with the product as we did with the order.

Comment: That could work, please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get remote product ID first using SKU, then update the remote product with live product data.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'on_product_savex', 10, 1 );
function on_product_savex( $product_id ) {
   $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
   $product_sku = $product->get_sku();
   $remote_keys = "consumer_key=xxxxxx&consumer_secret=xxxxxx";

   // retrieve product ID by SKU, return product properties
   $remote_get = wp_remote_get("https://web.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?sku={$product_sku}&{$remote_keys}");
   $remote_product = json_decode($remote_get['body'])[0];
   $remote_product_id = $remote_product->id;
   
   $body = array(
      'name' => $product->get_name(), // product title
      'status' => 'private', // product status, default: publish
      'regular_price' => $product->get_regular_price(),
      'sale_price' => $product->get_sale_price(),
      'description' => $product->get_description(),
      'sku' => $product->get_sku(),
      'weight' => $product->get_weight(),
      'manage_stock' => true,
      'stock_quantity' => 10,
   );

   $raw_response = wp_remote_post( "https://web.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/{$remote_product_id}?{$remote_keys}", 
      array(
         "headers" => array( "Content-Type" => "application/json" ),
         "timeout" => 30,                    
         "body" => json_encode( $body ),
      )
   );
}
```